# Tab bar with ios storyboard

Tags: ios5, ios-4.2

I have 6 ViewControllers and I need to show the tab bar only in 4 of them(viewcontroller 2,viewcontroller 3,view controller 4,viewcontroller 5). When I navigate using modal view controller from the 6th viewController to the 2nd viewcontroller, Tab bar does not show.

Answer (score 0):

If you are presenting VC2 from VC6 modally, you won't see VC2's containing controller. That is by design.

But you UI logic is probably wrong anyway. Modal presentation presents a viewController out of context - the expectation is that you will then return (pop off the stack) via the presenting controller, not navigate elsewhere (for example, via a tab).

How did you get TO VC6 from one of your tab views? If you need more help perhaps you should post a Storyboard-style sketch showing your intent.

Comment: thanks for your reply, pls tell your suggestion for this. i want tabbar in viewcontroller2 and in rootview controller

Comment: I suggest you put more detail into your question. As I said, you could post a storyboard-style sketch of how you want your viewControllers to fit together with arrows showing the navigation routes between them. that would help to make sense of what you want to achieve.